# Need to understand and improve the following query in oracle. I was told it deletes duplicates. Not sure how?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
delete from 
   location_in a
where 
  a.rowid > 
   any (
     select 
        B.rowid
     from 
        location_in b
     where 
        A.location_id = B.location_id);
commit;
```

Comment: In what way do you need to improve it?

Comment: If you don't know how it works, don't touch it and ask the person who set you this work to explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't understand a delete statement, try changing the `delete` to `select *` and run it to see which rows it's finding.

Here's another way to write the same statement. Maybe this will be more clear?

```
delete from 
   location_in A
where 
  EXISTS (select 'this is a duplicate' 
    from location_in B
    where A.location_id = B.location_id
      and A.rowid > B.rowid);
```

If there are multiple rows in `location_in` with the same `location_id`, this will delete any of them that have a higher `rowid` than the others - which will leave you with only one row, the one with the lowest `rowid`.